# Javascript "private" vs. instance properties

Tags: javascript, namespaces, closures

I'm doing some Javascript R&D and, while I've read **Javascript: The Definitive Guide** and **Javascript Object Oriented Programming**, I'm still having minor issues getting my head out of class based OOP and into lexical, object based OOP.

I love modules.  Namespaces, subclasses and interfaces. w00t.  Here's what I'm playing with:

```
var Classes = {
    _proto : {
        whatAreYou : function(){
            return this.name;
        }
    },
    Globe : function(){
        this.name = "Globe"
    },
    Umbrella : new function(){
        this.name = "Umbrella"
    }(),
    Igloo : function(){
        function Igloo(madeOf){
            this.name = "Igloo"
            _material = madeOf;
        }
        // Igloo specific
        Igloo.prototype = {
            getMaterial : function(){
                return _material;
            }
        }
        // the rest
        for(var p in Classes._proto){
            Igloo.prototype[p] = Classes._proto[p]
        }
        return new Igloo(arguments[0]);
    },
    House : function(){
        function House(){
            this.name = "My House"
        }
        House.prototype = Classes._proto
        return new House()
    }
}
Classes.Globe.prototype = Classes._proto
Classes.Umbrella.prototype = Classes._proto

$(document).ready(function(){    
    var globe, umb, igloo, house;

    globe     = new Classes.Globe();
    umb       = Classes.Umbrella;
    igloo     = new Classes.Igloo("Ice");
    house     = new Classes.House();

    var objects = [globe, umb, igloo, house]

    for(var i = 0, len = objects.length; i < len; i++){
        var me = objects[i];
        if("whatAreYou" in me){
            console.log(me.whatAreYou())
        }else{
            console.warn("unavailable")
        }
    }
})
```

Im trying to find the best way to modularize my code (and understand prototyping) and separate everything out.  Notice `Globe` is a function that needs to be instantiated with `new`, `Umbrella` is a singleton and already declared, `Igloo` uses something I thought about at work today, and seems to be working as well as I'd hoped, and `House` is another Iglooesque function for testing.

The output of this is:

```
Globe
unavailable
Igloo
My House
```

So far so good. The Globe prototype has to be declared outside the Classes object for syntax reasons, Umbrella can't accept due to it already existing (or instantiated or... dunno the "right" term for this one), and Igloo has some closure that declares it for you.

HOWEVER...

If I were to change it to:

```
var Classes = {
    _proto : {
        whatAreYou : function(){
            return _name;
        }
    },
    Globe : function(){
        _name = "Globe"
    },
    Umbrella : new function(){
        _name = "Umbrella"
    }(),
    Igloo : function(){
        function Igloo(madeOf){
            _name = "Igloo"
            _material = madeOf;
        }
        // Igloo specific
        Igloo.prototype = {
            getMaterial : function(){
                return _material;
            }
        }
        // the rest
        for(var p in Classes._proto){
            Igloo.prototype[p] = Classes._proto[p]
        }
        return new Igloo(arguments[0]);
    },
    House : function(){
        function House(){
            _name = "My House"
        }
        House.prototype = Classes._proto
        return new House()
    }
}
Classes.Globe.prototype = Classes._proto
Classes.Umbrella.prototype = Classes._proto

$(document).ready(function(){    
    var globe, umb, igloo, house;

    globe     = new Classes.Globe();
    umb       = Classes.Umbrella;
    igloo     = new Classes.Igloo("Ice");
    house     = new Classes.House();

    var objects = [globe, umb, igloo, house]

    for(var i = 0, len = objects.length; i < len; i++){
        var me = objects[i];
        if("whatAreYou" in me){
            console.log(me.whatAreYou())
        }else{
            console.warn("unavailable")
        }
    }
})
```

**and make `this.name` into `_name`** (the "private" property), it doesn't work, and instead outputs:

```
My House
unavailable
My House
My House
```

Would someone be kind enough to explain this one?  Obviously `_name` is being overwritted upon each iteration and not reading the object's property of which it's attached.

This all seems a little too verbose needing `this` and kinda weird IMO.

Thanks :)

Comment: because your "private" is global.

Comment: I originally had the `var` keyword in there, but missed putting it back in.  That's why you don't ask questions at 3am ;)

In any case, thank you for your responses, it makes a bit more sense now and the same solution applies.  Cheers!

Comment: You might be interested in [ES5 OO sugar](http://raynos.org/blog/17)

Comment: I've seen and used some of these libraries that allow for a more structured class OOP-style usage, but I still need to understand the language. Thanks though, I'm always lookin for good libs.

Comment: The article lists prototypical OO mechanisms. Not dirty classical OO emulations. My personal favourite is [combining extend and Object.create](https://gist.github.com/1441105)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You declare a global variable. It is available from anywhere in your code after declaration of this. Wherever you request to `_name`(more closely `window._name`) you will receive every time a  global. In your case was replaced _name in each function. Last function is House and there has been set to "My House"

Declaration of "private" (local) variables must be with **`var` statement**.

Check this out:

```
var foo = function( a ) { 
    _bar = a;
    this.showBar = function() { 
       console.log( _bar );
    }
};
var a = new foo(4);   // _bar ( ie window._bar) is set to 4

a.showBar(); //4


var b = new foo(1); // _bar  is set to 1
a.showBar(); //1
b.showBar(); //1

_bar = 5; // window._bar = 5; 
a.showBar();// 5
```

Should be:

```
var foo = function( a ) { 

    var _bar = a;
    // _bar is now visibled only from both that function
    // and functions that will create or delegate from this function,
    this.showBar = function() { 
       console.log( _bar );
    };
    this.setBar = function( val ) { 
        _bar = val;
    };
    this.delegateShowBar = function() { 
       return function( ) { 
           console.log( _bar );
       }
    }
};
foo.prototype.whatever = function( ){ 
    //Remember - here don't have access to _bar
};

var a = new foo(4);
a.showBar(); //4

_bar // ReferenceError: _bar is not defined  :)
var b = new foo(1);

a.showBar(); //4
b.showBar(); //1

delegatedShowBar  = a.delegateShowBar();
a.setBar(6);
a.showBar();//6
delegatedShowBar(); // 6
```

Answer (score 1):

If you remove the key word "this", then the _name is in the "Globe" scope.

Looking at your code.

```
var globe, umb, igloo, house;

globe     = new Classes.Globe();
umb       = Classes.Umbrella;
igloo     = new Classes.Igloo("Ice");
house     = new Classes.House();
```

At last the house will override the "_name" value in globe scope with the name of "My House".